# Posting Data to another domain thru code-behind of Asp.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Since we can't post data to cross domains, I want to post the data to my aspx page and a code-behind code will take the data and submit to cross domain *(which is not being operated by me, so I don't have permission to modify source code for jsonp)* and also the website to which I pass my post data is also returning a cookie which includes shopping cart info and I need to store it on my local browser cache as well.

Can you provide me some code on how to accomplish that?

Thanks..

What I know is I need to use `WebResponse` and `WebRequest` classes for that manner.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(VS.80).aspx) for that matter:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    // Define data to be posted
    var values = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "key1", "value1" },
        { "key2", "value2" },
    };

    // Send the POST request
    byte[] result = client.UploadValues("http://foo.com", values);

    // This will contain the cookie being set
    string cookie = client.ResponseHeaders[HttpResponseHeader.SetCookie];
}
```